# How to execute multiple ajax call functions in one call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Just curious about ajax calls, so I have multiple ajax call function which calls different `Url endpoints` but I find it sometimes one call fails and others get success.

Say I have these function and I know both calls works when I console log them, it returns me the value I needed however these calls will trigger once the page has loaded.

```
function xs () {
 $.ajax({
    url: 'api/endpoint1?loc="space"',
    method: 'GET'
    ...
 })
}
function xd () {
 $.ajax({
    url: 'api/endpoint2?name="x"',
    method: 'GET'
    ...
 })
}
```

How I trigger these functions and I call this file say `calls.js` in my html and this will fire the ajax calls. But sometimes only 1 of them will get a success or sometimes both.

```
function init() {
 xs();
 xd();
}
init();
```

So just wondering if there's a better way of handling multiple `AJAX` calls specially if you have more than 2.

Comment: This question isn't clear. What exactly are you missing?

Comment: @Liam Sorry that was a typo, well I just find it weird that some of my ajax calls fails and the others get successfully called. Say `function xs()` fails in the first load then it will get success in the 2nd but `function xd()` will fail.

Comment: You can insert xd() inside a xs() success/fail. Best practice is to do a single ajax call and doing on back-end the other business logic (if one fail call other etc..)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EN8nc/164/

Comment: I would recommend looking at promises - https://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: you wait for callback for all ajax request i hope this link helps you.  =>                                     https://css-tricks.com/multiple-simultaneous-ajax-requests-one-callback-jquery/

Comment: so you only want `xd()` to be called if `xs()` is successful?

Comment: No, I don't need to rely whether one is successful as in theory calling them individually like mine would give me success on both. But for some weird reason it doesn't

Comment: What? This question makes no sense. If ones failing then it's the server side code where the issue lies not the javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking to have the second request execute ***regardless*** of the outcome of the first (success **or** fail), call it via `jqXHR`'s `done`:

```
function xs() {
 $.ajax({
    url: 'api/endpoint1?loc="space"',
    method: 'GET'
    ...
 }).done(function(){
     $.ajax({
         url: 'api/endpoint2?name="x"',
         method: 'GET'
         ...
     });
   });
});
```

Otherwise, look into promises using `Promise.all()`:

You can read more into promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
init(){

    Promise.all( [
       $.ajax({
          url: 'api/endpoint1?loc="space"',
          method: 'GET'
          ...
       }),
       $.ajax({
           url: 'api/endpoint2?name="x"',
           method: 'GET'
           ...
       })
    ]).then(function(){
       //Some other code - Won't run until both requests have finished
    });     
}
```

Comment: Well my idea is to call them all at once without relying on the first function to success. In theory they all should get success calls because they're being called individually.

Comment: I edited to look into promises. Does that help get you any closer?

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 0;
function xs () {
$.ajax({
url: 'api/endpoint1?loc="space"',
method: 'GET',
success: function(data){
 if(i == 0){
   i++;
   xd();
 }

}
});
}

function xd () {
$.ajax({
url: 'api/endpoint2?name="x"',
method: 'GET',
success: function(data){
 if(i == 0){
   i++;
   xs();
 }
}
});
}
```

Comment: This is just going to loop forever...

Comment: your right now i realise

Comment: Now Try this code

Comment: Yeah that's just as bad. [A promise](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41185209/542251) would make much more sense. Also you now have a race condition. Which one do you call first or do you call both? Also explain your code please. Code only answers are not very useful

Comment: my logic is that when the value of var i = 0 then your function is call when its 1 then function not called i think this logic is right

Comment: So when `init()` is called what happens? I'll give you a clue https://jsfiddle.net/nv6vuLc1/

Comment: Actually a better illustration https://jsfiddle.net/nv6vuLc1/3/ ajax is async... you have a race condition....

Comment: in jsfiddel you add your alert outside the if and use my code... just try it

Comment: Look, this is wrong. Your not understanding what an async call is....[Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/542251)

Answer (score 0):

```
function xs () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/endpoint1?loc="space"',
        method: 'GET'
        ...
        success: function() {
            $.ajax({
               url: 'api/endpoint2?name="x"',
               method: 'GET'
               ...
            })
        }
    })
}

function init() {
 xs();
}
init();
```

Comment: I don't want to reply whether the first call get success, see the other comment above.

Answer (score 0):

You can see if it's a problem in your frontend or in the backend with the inspector of Chrome. In the Network tab filter by XHR. if you don't see both calls there it's a front end problem if not it's probably a problem with the response.

In other hands you can control when launch the calls. For example:

using the document ready:

```js
$(function(){ 
 //jQuery code here 
})
```

or using promises you can execute both and wait until you receive the data using promise.all()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 0):

Using [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS), you will be able to achieve what you describe, which is, if I understand correctly, launch several asynchronous calls in parallel, and then perform an action when all calls complete.

There's a (rather poorly documented last time I checked) feature called `forkJoin` just for that. Here's a sample (written in TypeScript but you get the idea) :

```
  /**
   * Get some Lists of Values.
   */
  public getLovs(codes: string[], lang: string) {
    return Observable.forkJoin(
        codes.map(code => { return this.getLov(code, lang); })
    );
  }
```

In this code, `getLov` returns an Observable (which is some kind of evolved Promise). The `getLovs` function itself returns an Observable when all async calls have been performed. The resulting Observable is an array comprised of the result each individual async call. Very useful.

Comment: He hasn't asked for an RxJs solution. there is no need to include this library to solve this problem and doing so would be massive overkill

Comment: OK so you downvote a solution that works but you don't downvote a solution that loops forever like the one above. Besides, as far as I can tell, no single answer in this thread except mine allows to launch multiple async calls in parallel as the OP seemed to request.

Comment: Actually I've downvoted both....

Comment: **if** thats what the OP wants (which isn't clear but well..) It's perfectly possible to achive this without the addition of a library

Comment: I wasn't asking you to downvote the other either. Of course the OP hasn't asked for an RxJs solution specifically, he asked for a solution that works according to his request.

Answer (score -1):

Put your Second `ajax` call inside the success/complete function of the first and it will execute for sure

Comment: but that will do a chain call which isn't the idea of the function above, otherwise I'd have done that. I want them to execute all at once. Plus this should be a comment than an answer.